# Finding a position of web images in a scrape

Tags: python, html, image, css, web-scraping

Is there a way to find a position (i.e. left and top offset) of an image on a website? Can it be done through web image scraping? The language I am using is Python.

Comment: what do you mean position here? like a coordinates for its four corners? in pixels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your definition of position is the x-y pixels coordinate of a picture(actually it could be any element). You can use Selenium to easily do that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://datafireball.com")
# I am using Chrome Developer Tool to get the Xpath, you might want to use your own code.
pic = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-174"]/div/p[5]/a/img')
position = pic.location
print(position)
```

The output is:

```
{'y': 727, 'x': 493}
```

Here is just a picture showing you that the x coordinate is correct. Same works for y. 
Note: when the browser is opened up by the Python code, the user might not actually see the picture directly. But the code will still capture the position. And it also depends on the profile of your browser. So you can set the default window size, zoom rate etc. for the browser to get reproducible result.

More information about Selenium set up, click [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=size#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_window_size).

[image]