# Get Relevant Image from webpage

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, jsoup, facebook-opengraph

User enters a query and I need to get webpage relevant to that query, once webpage is retrieved then I need to get important image from that webpage.

One approach might be to get the image defined in `Open Graph Protocol` image tag, the way facebook does it, but the problem is that not many websites are conforming to OGP at the moment and thus most of the times no image is returned.

The second approach might be to assign score to every image base on its size, aspect ratio e.t.c (as discussed in one of questions at SO)but at the moment I cant follow that approach due to some constraints.

The third approach that I was thinking is to see if the caption of the image contains any words from query, if it does then I can get that image.
Not many image contains captions, but atleast I can get ones which have caption.

The problem I am facing is that how to determine whether image has a caption or not? At the moment I am gettimg image element via BeautifulSoup library, and then I examine the next element. if next element contains text and if text contains words from query I get the image.
But a lot of captions gets missed and many times non-caption text is retrieved.

Do you have a better idea on how to tackle the problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the Open Graph Protocol so I will give my opinions about the second and third approaches.

The second approach:
It is really necessary to do some check before return a image to the user. It doesn't have to be very sophisticated, but imagine there is a picture actually is very small and basically doesn't contain any information. To some degree, it is not a qualified picture, many pictures for decoration purpose will fall into this category. Click [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/wp-content/themes/magazine-basic/images/nav.png) for an example.

You can easily get the height or width easily using BeautifulSoup and to get more information about image, you can use Selenium to get the [location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315715/finding-a-position-of-web-images-in-a-scrape/20316142#20316142) of a picture and other features to help you verify the quality of a picture.

The third approach:

I will say it is really hard to define "caption of a picture". You can use the `alt` attribute of a `img` tag to use as caption. If the caption is separated from the `img`, then it could be anything.. wrapped in a div, span, ...etc.  In this case, you can use some fuzzy match to ASSUME the text around the picture will be related with the picture. You can find the `parent` tag of the `img` and get all the text within that `parent` tag. If it still doesn't work well, you can search one level up. It will be much helpful if you have some knowledge of your target website. If not this might be a good starting point.

This is a paragraph of code that showing you the idea of grab image and the text around it:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open("http://www.r-bloggers.com/"))
imgs = soup.find_all("img")
captions = [img.parent.parent.text.encode('utf-8').strip() for img in imgs]
for img, caption in zip(imgs, captions):
    print img, caption
```

Here I am grabbing the parent.parent... you might want to change it to a legit level to meet your requirement.